# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n\log^2(n+1)}$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n\log^2(n+1)}.$$
>   Determine whether it converges **absolutely** or **conditionally**.

**My attempt**

S=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( -1)^n$ a<sub>n</sub>

a<sub>n</sub>  is monotonically decreasing and it approaches zero when n approaches infinity. So series is convergent .

**Doubt**

How to check for absolute convergence? Ratio test fails here.

Comment: Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n\log^2(n+1)}$?

Comment: To test the absolute convergence, you could try Cauchy's integral test.

Comment: Heh. When I first read this question, I assumed that $\log^2$ was the *iterated* logarithm ($\log\circ\log$), not the square. I am not sure if there is any firmly established convention in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the absolute convergence by [**cauchy condensation test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we can consider the convergenge of the condensed series $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ that is

$$\sum \frac{2^n}{2^n(\log^2(2^n+1))}=\sum \frac{1}{\log^2(2^n+1)}$$

which converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ indeed

$$\frac{1}{\log^2(2^n+1)}\sim\frac1{n^2\log^2 2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct, ratio test fails here. Hint: note that for $n\geq 3$,
$$0\leq \frac{1}{n(\log^2(n+1))}\leq \frac{1}{n(\log^2(n))}\leq \int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x(\log^2(x))}=\frac{1}{\log(n-1)}-\frac{1}{\log(n)}.$$

What may we conclude?

Answer (score 3):

Simply we have
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log^2(n+1)}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}$$
and one may use [the integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) for evaluating $\displaystyle\int_{2}^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log^2x}=\dfrac{1}{\log 2}$.

Comment: The value of the integral is $1/\log 2$ rather than $1/2$.

Comment: @Gary OK. Thanks.